# How to prevent users from manipulating html content "badly" and posting it back to server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have not found the same as or related to my question above.

If it is already asked, please let me know, I will delete mine.

I am learning asp.net mvc 2.

After downloading the rendered page, the visitors have a chance to manipulate the html contents ILLEGALLY and submit it back to the server. In MVC, how can I avoid this issue?

Comment: Use server side validation to avoid this issue. Validate everything that come from client!

Comment: How are 'visitors' doing this and what's the impact? Have you looked at the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prevent anything on the user side. Therefore you must ensure that the server reacts correctly to manipulated input.

Note that the automatic model binding is tricky: both over- and under-posting can cause trouble.
This is an excellent post on that topic: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks @Lucero for your answer and the link. I am reading now.

Answer (score 1):

Take all the efforts you can to validate the user input at the server. MVC offers the [AntiForgeryToken](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/29/AntiForgeryTokenInMVCFramework.aspx) which helps verify that the page being posted back is the correct page but as with any client-side verification, it's not foolproof.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion and the link. I have read it at a glance. I will re-read again after reading the link given by @Lucero.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything about this.

Use the mantra "never trust anything from your users" and validate everything on server side.